# Are there any tutorials out there on creating custom transform matrices for iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, transform

I want to jump in that stuff. Some good tutorials would be cool!

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html

that might be a good start point

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iPhone transform matrices don't exist.

You'll have to use regular ones :(

Comment: are you sure? I can do self.layer.transform.m32 for example...Xcode doesn't complain about it. I just need to find out how to alter these values...

Comment: Oh, those. Those are CGAffineTransforms. You can set their components directly (a, b, c, d, tx, ty).

Answer (score 0):

For CATransform3D (3-D Core Animation transforms), you can [refer to their documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW10), which does a good job of explaining the fundamentals.

If you're interested in examples, I describe how I improved some OpenGL rendering tasks by using the structure [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/01/13/opengl-es-catransform3d), and I have source code for an iPhone application that does 3-D rotation and perspective effects using CATransform3D and Core Animation [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball).